# Inheriting a templated conversion operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, template-meta-programming, c++20, conversion-operator

Consider the following code:

```
template <class R, class... Args>
using function_type = R(*)(Args...);

struct base {
    template <class R, class... Args>
    constexpr operator function_type<R, Args...>() const noexcept {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

struct derived: private base {
    template <class R, class... Args>
    using base::operator function_type<R, Args...>; // ERROR
};
```

Is there a working alternative in C++20 to inherit and expose a templated conversion function?

Comment: Afaics the current C++2a standard draft still contains the passage which blocks using using-declarations to refer to a specialization of a member template conversion function of a base class; http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#4.sentence-2.

Comment: Are there *other* conversion functions in `derived` that would otherwise hide the conversion function template in `base`?

Comment: @DavisHerring It's trying to change the access.

Comment: @T.C.: Right—I missed the private inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC support this: [[demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/95cQ-A)

```
template <class R, class... Args>
using function_type = R(*)(Args...);

struct base {
    template <class R, class... Args>
    constexpr operator function_type<R, Args...>() const noexcept {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

struct derived: private base {
  
    using base::operator function_type<auto, auto...>; // No error!
};


int main (){
  derived d;
  static_cast <int(*)(int)>(d);
}
```

But I think this is an extension to the language that may come from the concept-TS.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a working alternative in C++20 to inherit and expose a templated conversion function?

I don't know a way to directly expose it, through `using`.

But you can wrap it in a derived operator

```
struct derived: private base {

    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    constexpr operator function_type<R, Args...>() const noexcept {
       return base::operator function_type<R, Args...>();
    }

};
```